# Link should be applied if only condition gets true in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the react js. Here I have following code , I have one parameter which is isUplodMode so if this is true then that Link should not be there . only div should be or else It should be Link.

What I tried is:
This is the div which should get wrapped with Link or not.

```
return useObserver(() => (
     <div
            className={classNames({
              [css.ImageContainer]: true,
              [css.defaultImage]: !state.imageURI
            })}>
            {isUploadMode ? (
              <ImageUpload
                imageUrl={state.imageURI}
                onImageChange={onImageChange}
                onImageRemove={onImageRemove}></StandardImageUpload>
            ) : (
              <BgImage
                image={state.imageURI ? state.imageURI : defaultBuyingSessionImage}
              />
            )}
          </div>))
```

But this does not show if it is false but what I am trying is to have that div in any case . Only Link should be the one which can be and can not be with that div.

Comment: You just have to move the `div` out of the `Link` block

Comment: @LuísRamalho    But How do I because that div is the one on which user will click. Sorry But I did not got you and then where do I put the link.It would be great If you put as an answer so that if works I can accept that

Comment: {isUploadMode? <Link /> : <div />} ???

Comment: Yeah but It will be duplicate of code I guess

Comment: But Link should also have that div

Comment: I'm sorry, what link are you referring to? I see none in your question's code snippet. Is the single div in the snippet what you want wrapped in either a `Link` or `div`? Or is it either a `Link` *or* that `div`? Can you be bit more clear on what your expected results should be?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what you're trying to achieve. This is what you want to have. You will use this code where you are rendering the Link/div

```
{!isUploadMode && (
   <Link>
      {useObserver()}
   <Link/>
)}
{isUploadMode && (
    {useObserver()}
)}
```

If uploadMode is not set, it will output the div wrapped inside the link. If it is set, it will only output the div and not the link.